Let $f$ be a continuous function mapping the unit interval to the unit interval such that $\int_{0}^{x}f = \int_{x}^{1}f$. Prove that $f=0$.
Let $f$ be a continuous function mapping the unit interval to the unit interval such that $\int_{0}^{x}f = \int_{x}^{1}f$. Prove that $f=0$.
I´ve tried doing a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $f\neq0$ so that there exists some $x_{0} \in (0,1)$ such that $0<f(x_{0})\leq 1$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a neighbourhood of $x_{0}$ where $f>0$. Thus we can pick $\delta\geq r >0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(x_{0}-\delta, x_{0}+\delta)$. Now note that
$$
0= \int_{0}^{0}f = \int_{0}^{1}f.
$$
Hence,
$$
0 = \int_{0}^{1}f = \int_{0}^{x_{0}-\delta}f + \int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}f + \int_{x_{0}+\delta}^{1}f.
$$
Since the integral preserves the order, we have $0<\int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}f\leq 1$. Similarly $0\leq \int_{0}^{x_{0}-\delta}f \leq 1,\ 0\leq \int_{x_{0}+\delta}^{1} f \leq 1$. So the right hand side of the equality is stricttly greater than $0$, which implies that $0>0$, a contradiction. I´m not sure if this is correct because the fact that $f(x)\leq 1$ is not strictly neccesary in my proof. I´ve also thought about using $F(x) =\int_{0}^{x} f$ for $x\in [0, 1]$ and trrying to prove that $F' = 0$. I could use Rolle´s theorem to find some $c\in(0,1)$ where $F'(c) = 0$, but that is just some point not the whole interval. Another thing I´ve noticed is that in that case $F$ is Lipschtz with Lipschitz constant 1, since
$$
|F(x)-F(y)| = F'(c)|x-y|\leq |x-y|
$$
for some $c\in(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary. But I don´t know right now if this could be useful in this case.

Simpler: What do you get if you differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$?

If $f$ is continuous, those integral expressions are differentiable functions of $x$. What are the implications of differentiating each side?

Yes that was the first thing I thought, but since differentiating on both sides doesn´t use the fact that $0\leq f(x) \leq 1$ I thought that there should be something that I was missing.
